# Are "class functions" referred to as "functions" or "methods" in Python

Tags: python, terminology

See the code below

```
class HelloWorld:
    def print(self):
        print "Hello World"
```

Is `HelloWorld.print(self)` called a *method* or a *function* in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are referred to as class methods or instance methods.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest answer is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Jakob's clear answer, in languages like Python there is no requirement that everything lives within a class, unlike (say) Java. So whereas in Java every function is a method, in Python this isn't true: many or even most functions aren't part of a class. That's why it makes sense to have this terminology distinction between methods and functions.